# Shortest path in "two-graph" with limited number of changes

Tags: c++, c, dijkstra, shortest-path, directed-graph

Let's say we have two directed and positive-weighted graphs on one set of vertices (first graph represents for example rail-roads and the second one - bus lanes; vertices are bus stops or rail-road stations or both). We need to find the shortest path from A to B, but we can't change the type of transport more than N times.

I was trying to modify the Dijkstra's algorithm, but it's working only on a few "not-so-mean-and-complicated" graphs and I think I need to try something different.

How to best represent that "two-graph" and how to manage the limited amount of changes in traversing the graph? Is there a possibility to adapt Dijkstra's algorithm in this one? Any ideas and clues will be helpful.

**Edit:** Well I forgot one thing (I think it's quite important): N = 0,1,2,...; we can come up with any graph representation we like and of course there can exist maximum 4 edges between every two nodes (1 bus lane and 1 railroad in one direction, and 1 bus lane and 1 railroad in the second direction).

Comment: "digraph" also is a letter pair like "ae", retagged.

Comment: How are the two graphs related? *Are* they two graphs?

Comment: I don't see any problems with modifying Dijkstra. You simply add a branch-and-bound component to Dijkstra, removing those paths that exceed the number of allowable changes from the list of paths permanently.

Comment: Or just not add such neighbors in the successor function in the first place.

Comment: @Electro: Yeah, or that. It's just a matter of implementation from that point on.

Comment: What exacty was problem with your current algorithm?

Comment: Seems like a pretty tough problem to solve in general.  Do you have constraints on `N`?

Comment: @arne unless I am missing something there is no obvious naive way to modify Dijkstra that works in reasonable time complexity.  If you really have such a modification do you mind describing it briefly, in more detail?

Comment: @Andrey: Will do as soon as I get home and have a little time.

Comment: N can be any number (0,1,2,...) and you can come up with any graph representation you like. Of course there can exist maximum 4 edges between every two nodes (1 bus lane and 1 railroad in one direction, and 1 bus lane and 1 railroad in the second direction). Anyway thanks for some advices... I'm gonna experiment more with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Ah, this is graph search with constraints on a [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) which can't be just transformed into an ordinary graph. As @Andrey said, I'm not sure this can be done with acceptable time complexity with a naive modification of Dijkstra's algorithm. If B is on the optimal path from A to C, the optimal path from A to B is not necessarily a feasible subpath.

Comment: After re-reading @Jarod42's answer, I think I take most of that back. It should work, though depending on N it might be substantially slower.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the best way, but you can create Nodes as follow:

```
Node:(NodeId, GraphId, correspondenceLeftCount)
```

(the total number of nodes will be `number_of_initial_nodes * number_of_graphs * number_of_correspondences_allowed`)

So:

For edge where `GraphId` doesn't change, `correspondenceLeftCount` doesn't change neither.
You add a new Edge for correspondance:

`(NodeId, Graph1, correspondenceLeftCount)` -> (NodeId, Graph2, correspondenceLeftCount - 1)`

And for the request A->B:
Your start point are `(A, graph1, maxCorrespondenceLeftCount)` and `(A, graph2, maxCorrespondenceLeftCount)`.
And your end points are `(B, graph1, 0)`, ... , `(B, graph1, maxCorrespondenceLeftCount)`, `(B, graph2, 0)`, ... , `(B, graph2, maxCorrespondenceLeftCount)`.

So you may to have to adapt your Dijkstra implementation for the *end condition*, and to be able to insert more than one start point.